# Get all matches from Html in Regex with Singleline

Tags: c#, regex

I'm having a problem of detecting all matches from this string. What i want is to get "all" matches from the `<p><[CDATA[<!--....-->]]></p>`

Here is my sample Html

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="twelve columns">
<p>
    <![CDATA[<!--@ControlViewHelper.ExpandableArea(Message.F_CMNG1010(), @<text>
@ControlViewHelper.TextArea(Message.CMNL_USER(), "userid", ""))-->]]>
<p>
    <![CDATA[<!--@ControlViewHelper.ExpandableArea(Message.CMNL_PASSWORD(), @<text>
</text>)-->]]>
</p>
<p>
    <![CDATA[<!--@ControlViewHelper.ExpandableArea(null, @<text>

</text>)-->]]>
</p>
<p>
    <![CDATA[<!--@ControlViewHelper.ExpandableArea(null, @<text>

</text>)-->]]>
</p>

    </div>
</div>
```

And this is my current regex with SingleLine and Global activated

```
<p>[\r*\n*\t*\s*]*<!\[CDATA\[<!--(.*)-->\]\]>[\r*\n*\t*\s*]*<\/p>
```

The result is always **only one** and because it detects the first `<p>` and last `</p>`

---

New problem, it seems that a non greedy marker solved it, now i have this regex.

```
<p>[\r*\n*\t*\s*]*<!\[CDATA\[(.*?)\]\]>[\r*\n*\t*\s*]<\/p>
```

But this fails on this html.

```
<p>
    <![CDATA[@ControlViewHelper.ExpandableArea(Message.F_CMNG1010(), @<text>
    <p><![CDATA[@ControlViewHelper.TextArea(Message.CMNL_USER(), "userid",
    "")]]></p> </text>)]]>
</p>
<p>
    <![CDATA[@ControlViewHelper.ExpandableArea(Message.CMNL_PASSWORD(), @<text>
    <p><![CDATA[@ControlViewHelper.ExpandableArea(Message.CMNL_PASSWORD(), @<text>TEMPORARY
    CODE: Support for inline html as parameters not yet
    implemented.</text>)]]><p><![CDATA[@ControlViewHelper.TextBox(null,
    "KceQOpKT")]]></p><p><![CDATA[@ControlViewHelper.TextBox(null,
    "FYkeojGu")]]></p><p><![CDATA[@ControlViewHelper.TextBox(Message.CMNL_PASSCHECK(),
    "qCpXFoIX")]]></p></p> </text>)]]>
</p>
<p>
    <![CDATA[@ControlViewHelper.ExpandableArea(null, @<text> </text>)]]>
</p>
<p>
    <![CDATA[@ControlViewHelper.ExpandableArea(null, @<text> </text>)]]>
</p>
```

It cant detect the CDATA without the `[\r*\n*\t*\s*]`

Comment: The pattern is not going to match correctly because the first `CDATA` has no `</p>`

Comment: You just need to use a non-greedy quantifier: `(.*?)`.  And maybe drop the `</p>`, if that one is really missing as @l'L'l observed.

Comment: @AlanMoore that seems to be working, now how do i make the group of whitespaces and return `[\r*\n*\t*\s*]` optional, say they don't exist?

Comment: @l'L'l i've fixed that missing tag, nice find though.

Comment: @AlanMoore I've also updated the question

Comment: `\s` matches any whitespace character, not just the space, so all you need is `\s*`.

Comment: @AlanMoore got it with two regex match calls, one with the `[\s*]*` and one without. Thanks.

Mind posting an answer? so i can close the question?

Comment: When I said `\s*` is all you need, I meant that's all you need.  `[\s*]*` matches a whitespace character *or an asterisk* (`*`), zero or more times.  But I think I was wrong to say a non-greedy quantifier would solve your problem.  Does your HTML really have nested CDATA sections?  Last time I checked, that wasn't possible; the HTML parser always stops at the first closing `]]>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll suggest trying following regex. Note: Regex syntax highly depends on language it's being used. e.g.

in PHP and javascript:

```
/<p>\s*<!\[CDATA\[(?:<!--)?([\S\s]*?)(?:-->)?\]\]>\s*<\/p>/gi
```

in C#:

```
var htmlString = ""; // your html goes here
var result = null;

var regexObj = new Regex(@"<p>.*?<!\[CDATA\[(?:<!--)?(.*?)(?:-->)?\]\]>.*?<\/p>", 
               RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);

result = regexObj.Match(htmlString).Value;
```

Regex above will find `<p><[CDATA[<!--....-->]]></p>`. It may contain embedded/nested `<p><[CDATA[<!--....-->]]></p>` but you can easily check/remove using regex mentioned above again.

See demo at: 
https://regex101.com/r/nU4eZ4/4

Comment: `<` and `>` have no special meaning in regexes, but in some flavors, `\<` and `\>` are word boundaries.  Also, he said he's using the .NET flavor (C#) with Singleline mode set, so `(.*?)` will match across newlines.

Comment: Sometime < > are being used in named captures. So I was extra conscious. Better to be safe than sorry :). But thanks for pointing out. I'll update regex to C# flavor.

Comment: In Perl-derived regex flavors like .NET, it's *supposed* to be safe to escape any non-alphanumeric character, whether it's a metacharacter or not.  This is the only exception I know of, and very few flavors make it (Boost is one).  But angle brackets never need escaping, any more than colons, equals signs, or exclamation points do.  The only time they have special meanings is when they're part of a special group construct (they appear after `(?`, which is otherwise a syntax error).

Comment: Yes, I agree. It's safe in .NET and as you can see I have cleaned it up.

Comment: This is great!! Thanks for your effort